# Open dropdown on span click

Tags: javascript, onclick, dropdown

I need to open a submenu, clicking on the parent element. I could do it this way

```
$(function(){
  
  $('li.dropdown > a').on('click',function(event){
    
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().find('ul').first().toggle(300);
    
    $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').hide(200);
    
    //Hide menu when clicked outside
    $(this).parent().find('ul').parent().mouseleave(function(){ 
      var thisUI = $(this);
      $('html').click(function(){
        thisUI.children(".dropdown-menu").hide();
    thisUI.children("a").removeClass('selected');
               
        $('html').unbind('click');
      });
    });
       
  });
  
});
```

But, sometimes I have an actual link as a parent element. And I'd want to go to that link on click. And open the dropdown otherwise. Tried with a click on dropdown:before/ dropdown:after pseudoelements with no luck. And I can't manage to do it adding a span inside dropdown div.

Thank you for any help.

LE: My HTML structure looks like this

```
<nav id="main-nav">
  <ul>
    
    <li><a href="http://test.com" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
    
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="http://test.co/main-cat">Main Cat</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="http://test.co/main-cat/sub1">Sub Cat1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://test.co/main-cat/sub2">Sub Cat2</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://test.co/main-cat/sub3">Sub Cat3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li><a href="http://test.com">Second Cat</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: binding a click inside of a click is a BAD idea. Every time you click, you are adding another click event to the html element.

Comment: @hev1 updated my question with the HTML